# Cursor disappears after suspending and then logging back in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, cursor

My cursor disappears after suspending and then logging back in Lubuntu

I don't know why this happens, I tried default settings for the cursor, different theme, ... but with no result.

Comment: Please add Information about your Lubuntu version. There are different init-Systems and we can only guess what you are using

Comment: @KevInski Latest LTS version, 32 bits

Comment: I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 15.10 but only after resuming from sleep. I just opened a terminal and typed `sudo service lightdm restart` This may help you. After a time systemd learns and restarts it automatically. At least that's what a co-worker told me.

Comment: @KevInski Found a much better temporary solution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporary solution, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> the mouse re-appears.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that, if you manage to place the invisible cursor over a text box, click on it and start typing, it re-appears instantly. I know where my cursor is because it highlights text boxes and other things when it passes over them, I don't know if you can see it.

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04.1 on a Samsung n210 netbook BTW.