# Can't see mouse icon when returning from suspend

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, mouse, suspend

In the following setup:

- OS -> Ubuntu 14.04.1 (totally updated)
- Desktop Environment -> XFCE
- PC -> Lenovo E540 (i5-4210M, 8GB RAM, Intel HD 4600)
- Secondary Screen -> Samsung S19C45

I have the following issue:

Every time I suspend the laptop and come back again, I lose the mouse icon. I have to move the mouse to the second display to recover it. If the laptop is not connected to a secondary display, I have to log out and log in to recover the mouse icon.

What can I do?

Comment: I also had this behaviour with 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04 on an HP Desktop at work, I always needed to `sudo service lightdm restart` in a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) or on another tty (ctrl+alt+F1). Because the window-manager will be restarted, all opened windows are gone, so save all your work.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem. With the log out & log in that I do is like restarting lightdm. Hope someone can solve or give us some idea.

Comment: Well, I am on 16.04 now and I never had that problem again.

Comment: Related: [Cursor disappears after suspending and then logging back in Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/815289/37165) and [Mouse pointer missing after suspend...](https://askubuntu.com/q/780240/37165). In my case, "mouse cursor missing after suspend" issue was resolved some time ago after updating kernel packages.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+F1 followed by Ctrl+Alt+F7 also help?

Comment: @dessert yeah! That  works!

Comment: Using [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/815289/37165) I can recover the mouse icon. But it isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This **does not solve** the issue, but at least saves you the troubles of having to log out and log in every single time:

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>F6</kbd> followed by <kbd>F7</kbd>.

The first may be any one from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>, choose your favorite wisely as the effect will be the exact same.

---

To automate this with a script you can use `chvt`:

```
sudo chvt 6 && sudo chvt 7
```

---

Now to automatically execute these commands without having to enter your password every time, follow these steps:

1. Create a script:

   ```
   echo -e '#!/bin/sh\n[ $1 = post ] && [ $2 = suspend ] && chvt 6 && chvt 7' > makemouseappear
   ```
2. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod a+x makemouseappear
   ```
3. Move it to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`:

   ```
   sudo mv makemouseappear /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
   ```
4. Try it out and rejoice:

   ```
   systemctl suspend
   ```

   NB: It won't wake up automatically.

Instead of or beside `suspend` you may use different modes like `hibernate` or `hybrid-sleep`, those are not covered by the above script unless you change `&& [ $2 = suspend ]` to

- `&& [ $2 = hibernate ]` to execute it after hibernate mode
- `&& [ $2 = hybrid-sleep ]` to execute it after hybrid-sleep mode
- *nothing* (just delete it) to execute it after every return from one of the three mentioned modes

See [man systemd-sleep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/systemd-sleep.8.html) for details.

Please be aware that this is **still just a workaround**, only that its dirtyness now hides deep down in `/lib/systemd/`.

Comment: Oh! Pretty cool! At least is an automate of the process.  I'll upvote you but leave the question without answer. Hope someone find a way. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Does my automatic workaround help you? Of course I couldn't test it with your exact problem…

Comment: Didn't try yet. I'll try it and tell you something.